# How to clean eclipse cache Neon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am having work-space related conflicts in my eclipse neon setup. Is there a standard way to clean my eclipse setup? And make it as new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "workspace related conflicts" but there is a "-clean" (osgi.clean) [runtime option](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) which might help.

> **-clean (OSGi)**
> equivalent to setting osgi.clean to "true"
>
> **osgi.clean**
> if set to "true", any cached data used by the OSGi framework and eclipse runtime will be wiped clean. This will clean the caches used to store bundle dependency resolution and eclipse extension registry data. Using this option will force eclipse to reinitialize these caches.